# What does the .size on number mean in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Why is my ruby giving incorrect size of number?  It doesn't matter what's the number. The output is always 4 for the size. What does that mean? I always thought it should give the number of digits.

```
number = 14
print number
print "\n"
print number.size
```

output:

```
14
4
```

ruby version

```
ruby 2.1.8p440 (2015-12-16 revision 53160) [i386-mingw32]
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could tell us (or even better yet file a bug on the Ruby bug tracker about it) what *specifically* in the documentation of that method is unclear to you. That way, the Ruby developers can improve the documentation for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: A number is a quantity; it doesn't have digits. It has the same value no matter how do you represent it; one can represent it as decimal, binary, hexadecimal or even using Roman numerals. Its value is still the same. The number of digits (in the decimal representation) can be easily found using `number.to_s.length`. I.e. by counting the number of characters (digits) needed to represent it in decimal. `number.to_s(16).length` gets you the number of digits used to represent the value in base 16.

Comment: It is no always `4` : `32.size #=> 8` and `(2**128).size #=> 17`

Comment: It also depends on your architecture: `1.size #=> 4` indicates a 32 bit system (hence `mingw32`), whereas `1.size #=> 8` indicates a 64 bit system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I always suggest to check the method you're not sure about using the following scheme:

1. Check where the method comes from (using [Object#`method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-method)):

   ```
   number.method(:size)
   #=> #<Method: Fixnum#size>
   ```
2. Open docs and learn what it does for `Fixnum#size` and how it works.

   2.1 If you're using IRB, you can run `help 'Fixnum#size'` to get the docs right in your console
   2.2 If you're using pry, you can go with `show-doc Fixnum#size` (install `pry-doc` gem first)

---

In Ruby 2.1.8 method was defined in [Fixnum#`size`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.8/Fixnum.html#method-i-size).

Starting from Ruby 2.4 it's defined in
[Integer#`size`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Integer.html#method-i-size):

> Returns the number of bytes in the machine representation of int.

Comment: You can also enter `help 'Fixnum#size'` right in IRB.

Comment: @Stefan cool! never used it, because it's not working in `pry`

Comment: @AndreyDeineko You can use `show-doc Fixnum#size` in `pry` though.

Comment: @MichaelKohl if I have installed `pry-doc` gem, but yea :) Edited the answr

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing the two methods [`String#size`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-size):

> Returns the character length of `str`.

and [`Fixnum#size`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Fixnum.html#method-i-size):

> Returns the number of bytes in the machine representation of `fix`.

`14` is an object of class `Fixnum`, so when you call `size` on it you are getting the number of bytes in the machine representation of the number.

If you would like to know how many digits there are in a number, you can simply convert it to a string first and then call `size` on that:

```
14.to_s
# => "14"
14.to_s.size
#=> 2
12345.to_s.size
#=> 5
```

Comment: Or `12345.digits.size` in newer Rubies.

Comment: @Stefan I don't know why but some tools doesn't recognize "digits.size"... It's sad.